# Java Send Mail : javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-mail

I was trying to send a mail from a java application. I didnt use any authentication as i already stored the from address in database after authentication. This is a scheduled email, so i can't get the password while sending the the mail. So i stored the email ids in a table firstly after authentication and then scheduled the email.
Please check the following code

```
public void sendMessage(EmailMessage emailMessage) {
    Properties props = mailConfiguration.getProps();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailMessage.getFromAddress()));
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(emailMessage.getToAddress()));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(emailMessage.getSubject());
        mimeMessage.setContent(emailMessage.getMessage(), "text/html");
        mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
        Transport.send(mimeMessage);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        Timestamp sendTime = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
        emailMessage.setGeneratedTime(sendTime);
        emailMessage.setStatus(MessageStatus.SENT);
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
        log.error("Username and Password not accepted." + e.getMessage(), e);
        emailMessage.setStatus(MessageStatus.ERROR);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.error("An exception occurred while sending mail from [" + emailMessage.getFromAddress() + "] to [" + emailMessage.getToAddress() + "] : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        emailMessage.setStatus(MessageStatus.ERROR);
    }
    log.info("Changing message status of Email Message " + emailMessage.getId() + " to " + emailMessage.getStatus());
    emailMessageRepository.save(emailMessage);
}
```

The email configuration looks like

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfiguration {

Properties props = new Properties();

 public MailConfiguration() {
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.debug", "false");
 }

 public Properties getProps() {
    return props;
 }
}
```

The problem is i can't send email using this. Instead i get an exception like

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: null

What is the problem ?
I searched almost similar questions here. But they don't explain my scenario

Comment: can you add more logs, before and after?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate.  Storing the From address in a database is not enough.